# how to store the result of sed in variable with the new line characters

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed

i tries storing data of sed in this way,

```
line=$(sed 's/old/new/g' data.t)
```

but the problem is newline do not get stored in a variable.
the sed command produces a output in which there are new lines the variable doesnt stores the new lines while i want to store them.
How can i store newline in the variable too?

Comment: Why do you want newlines in line? Could you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newline is there, you just need to quote the variable properly to see it. `echo` is not a very good command for inspecting your variables,but this should work like you want:

```
echo "$line"
```

Answer (score 2):

It  does keep the newlines, but to see them when you use it, you need to double quote it

```
$ a=$(echo -e "a\nb\nc")
$ echo $a
a b c
$ echo "$a"
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
line="$(sed 'a/old/new/s' data.t)"

echo "$line"
```

I'm not sure about your sed cmd, 'a/old/new/s'. I would have expected to see something like 's/old/new/g', but good luck.

I hope this helps.